# Tomcat and Absent Code attribute in method that is not native or abstract in class file

Tags: jsf, jakarta-ee, tomcat7, netbeans-7, java-6

I use Tomcat 7, JSF2.1, JSTL 1.1 JDK 1.6, EclipeLink for JPA and Netbeans 7.1.2

I have this problem.
javax.servlet.ServletException: Absent Code attribute in method that is not native or abstract in class file...

I have read in many forums that just add the libraries JavaEE version 6 with the ones I've tried to import into NetBeans does not work.
Can anyone tell me how to do
Thanks in Advance

Comment: How are you adding the libraries in your project? Maven?

Comment: This is my library: JSF 2.1-jsf-api.jar, JSF 2.1-jsf-impl.jar, JSTL1.1-standard.jar, JSTL1.1-jstl.jar, eclipselink-2.3.0,javax.persistence-2.0,org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.jpql_1.0.0, mysql.jar....

Comment: I don't use maven in this case but simple NetBeans Libraries Manager.

Comment: I noticed that if I add servlet-api.2.5.jar me no longer have this problem and it says it does not work javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: most likely not work anymore expression language to retrieve the methods of Beans

Comment: I also tried this but it does not work                          jsf20.classpath
jstl11.classpath
MySQLDriver.classpath
primefaces-3.3.1.jar
commons-codec-1.6.jar
commons-io-2.4.jar
commons-fileupload-1.2.2.jar
eclipselink.jar
eclipselink-jpa-modelgen_2.4.0.v20120608-r11652.jar
javax.persistence_2.0.4.v201112161009.jar
eclipse.persistence.jpars.source_2.4.0.v20120608-r11652.jar
org.eclipse.persistence.jpars_2.4.0.v20120608-r11652.jar
org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.jpql_1.0.0.jar